# Spring boot 3.2.1: An Expected CSRF token cannot be found

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

I have used spring boot parent version 3.2.1, Spring security 6, Spring cloud version: 2023.0.0, Spring cloud gateway starter version: 4.1.0 and JDK 17.

With above configuration I have created and gateway application.  We have spring security a separate project and I have added that project with its maven dependency. In spring security class we have explicitly **disabled** the **CSRF**. When I am calling gateway URL using postman then I'm getting error: **An Expected CSRF token cannot be found  **

I'm unable to understood from where this csrf token is enabled because in security layer csrf token is already disabled explicitly .

Comment: Show us your "web security" configuration plus a DEBUG log with the reqeust being rejected, otherwise we cannot help you at all.

Comment: As @Manuel suggested , Please provide Web Security Configuration code and debug log